# Missing lot of options in Wordpress dashboard Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have recently installed wordpress in my bluehost hosting. However It installed it through Mojo Market Place. After successfull installation I notice there were lot of features / options was missing in my dashboard as compared to standard wordpress installation like appearance, plugins, users, tools settings etc. as you can see it in below screenshot. Due to which I am not able to perform addtional task. How do I get all standard features provided by wordpress?

[image]

Comment: Install it manually, do not use Mojo Market Place. It might have installed a light version or an old one.

Comment: That I have done. But how will I get the settings I have done in my old website like menus creation & some css effects. In short I want same settings as per my old installation